# C# LINQ expression cannot be translated when summing group joins

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables: users and transactions. The transactions table stores user wallet transactions (+ balance, - balance) etc. I'm trying to obtain a list of users based on the current balance of their wallet ordered by largest first. (I can get the total balance by summing the `Amount` column in the `Transactions` table).

```
var query = from u in _context.users
                        join t in _context.Transactions on u.id equals t.UserId into gj
                        from txn in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where txn.TransactionStatus == Transaction.Status.Success && !u.Deleted.HasValue
                        select new
                        {
                            balance = gj.Sum(a => a.Amount),
                            user = u,
                        };

            var result = await query.OrderByDescending(t => t.balance).Skip(offset).Take(range).ToListAsync();
```

I am getting the error:

> The LINQ expression 'gj' could not be translated.

This is the equivalent SQL I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT balance, u.* FROM

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount), 0) as balance, u.id
  FROM dbo.users u
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Transactions t ON(u.id = t.UserId AND t.TransactionStatus = 0)
  WHERE u.Deleted IS NULL
  GROUP BY u.id) as tbl

JOIN dbo.users u ON(u.id = tbl.id)
ORDER BY balance DESC
```

Comment: Unless you really did mean to have all users plus only transactions for non deleted users, it's redundant to write the sql with two joins to users; you can either remove the user table from the sub query and test for deleted in the main query where it even just do it all at one level; `select u.*, sum(amount) from users left join trans on ... where deleted is null group by every,column,in,users`. You don't need to coalesce for SUM's benefit this way; nulls aren't part of the agg operation so if the only record out of the left join is users with null amount (no transactions) the sum will be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from users and using the navigation props to go through to Trans should make this trivial. Give something like this a go:

```
users.Where(u => u.Deleted == null)
.Select(u => new {
    User = u,
    Balance = u.Transactions.Where(t => t.Status == 0).Sum(t => t.Amount)
})
.OrderByDescending(at => at.Balance);
```

If the logic truly is "list all users but only add up transactions for users that are non deleted, and show deleted users as 0 balance" then:

```
users.Where(u => u.Deleted == null)
.Select(u => new {
    User = u,
    Balance = u.Deleted != null ? 0 : u.Transactions.Where(t => t.Status == 0).Sum(t => t.Amount)
})
.OrderByDescending(at => at.Balance);
```

Try not to write EF queries like "right, in SQL I would have this table and join that table, and it'd be a left join, and that would be summed... so I'll tell EF to do this context set join that context set, and it's a left join, and sum..." - EF will write joins for you; express your requirements in terms of how you want the C# object graph to be manipulated and let EF do the conversion to SQL how it can; use the navigation props between entities so it can work out how you want to bring your data together and arrange the necessary joins. It seldom needs micromanaging in a SQL-ey flavored approach

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I was way overcomplicating things.